# MongoDB text search has an abysmal performance compared to Lucene

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

I have tried to use MongoDB's text search but the performance compared to Lucene has been abysmal.
Before switching back to Lucene, I'd like to see if anyone can spot a mistake in the MongoDB code that could explain the perfomance problems.

I have a Mongo collection of objects, called MongoPost, that contains:
- A list of text strings to be used in a text search
- A list of fields to be used for sorting, such as dates, various counts, etc
- Data irrelevant to the search

The index creation is done the following way:

```
_Driver = Database.GetCollection<MongoPost>("Posts");
_Driver.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<MongoPost>.IndexKeys.Ascending(_ => _._id), new CreateIndexOptions { Unique = true }).Wait();
_Driver.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<MongoPost>.IndexKeys.Ascending(_ => _.Guid)).Wait();
_Driver.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<MongoPost>.IndexKeys.Ascending(_ => _.Status)).Wait();
_Driver.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<MongoPost>.IndexKeys.Ascending(_ => _.Category)).Wait();
_Driver.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<MongoPost>.IndexKeys.Ascending(_ => _.Type)).Wait();
_Driver.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<MongoPost>.IndexKeys.Ascending(_ => _.IsChecked)).Wait();
_Driver.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<MongoPost>.IndexKeys.Descending(_ => _.Quality)).Wait();
_Driver.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<MongoPost>.IndexKeys.Descending(_ => _.CreationTime)).Wait();
_Driver.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<MongoPost>.IndexKeys.Descending(_ => _.Score)).Wait();
_Driver.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<MongoPost>.IndexKeys.Descending(_ => _.Views)).Wait();
_Driver.Indexes.CreateOneAsync(Builders<MongoPost>.IndexKeys.Text(_ => _.Tags).Text(_ => _.Title)).Wait();
```

The search is done the following way:

```
var F = Builders<MongoPost>.Filter.Eq(_ => _.Category, Category)
      & Builders<MongoPost>.Filter.Eq(_ => _.Type, Type)
      & Builders<MongoPost>.Filter.Eq(_ => _.Status, Status)
      & Builders<MongoPost>.Filter.Eq(_ => _.IsChecked, IsChecked)
      & Builders<MongoPost>.Filter.Text(Text);

var P = Builders<MongoPost>.Projection.MetaTextScore(TEXTMATCHSTRING)
       .Exclude(_ => _._id)
       .Include(_ => _.Guid)
       .Include(_ => _.Tags)
       .Include(_ => _.Urls)
       .Include(_ => _.Views);

var S = Builders<MongoPost>.Sort.Descending(_ => _.CreationTime);

var Cursor = Mongo.Driver.Find(F.Data);
var Count = (int)Cursor.CountAsync().Result; // we need the count value
return Cursor.Project<MongoPostThumb>(P).Sort(S).Skip(Skip).Limit(Take).ToListAsync().Result;
```

The performance is about 150x lower than in Lucene!
After some testing, I found that the sort is taking most of the query's time.
Even without sort, the text search is way too slow to be acceptable, but the sort takes a good 70-80%.

The tests were done with a collection of about 600k items.

Is there something obvious I have been missing?

Comment: Surprise, surprise! An engine specialized on text search (and demanding quite some resources) is faster at text search than a database engine where text search is only a secondary feature. ;) As far as I can see, you only have a text index on the title and the tags field and several (in this case useless) other indices. However, your are querying other fields, too, causing a collection scan (aka "read every document (from disk if you have to) and compare" ). There are other issues, but that's the main thing, as far as I can see.

Comment: I didn't expect the same performance, but 150x is quite a gap!
The query is on Category, Type, Status, IsChecked and the Text; all of those are in the index.
(Other indexes are needed because of other unrelated queries, I should have removed from the code I posted). Where do you see the collection scan happening?